# Java FileWriter, append lines to different parts of a file

Tags: java, append, file-handling, filewriter

I am writing a quicksort program, where I need to store the results in a file. The structure of the file is:

Sorting result:
input1.txt sorted: -12; -9; 1; 5; 10; 10; 12; 100; 200; 200; 201; 201; 300; 300; 301; 301; 302; 302

Performance analysis:

Input file   Size  Sorting Time (in milliseconds)

input1.txt    18         1

---

Now, if I run the program with a different file name then, my program should append the 2nd files' data at sorting result and performance

Sorting result:
input1.txt sorted: -12; -9; 1; 5; 10; 10; 12; 100; 200; 200; 201; 201; 300; 300; 301; 301; 302; 302

input2.txt sorted: -12; -9; 1; 5; 10; 10; 12

Performance analysis:

Input file   Size  Sorting Time (in milliseconds)

input1.txt   18       1

input2.txt   7        0.5

How should I go about doing this in Java?. Right now I'm able to append to the file at the end, not in between as required. I am using a FileWriter object

```
writeToAnswers = new FileWriter(new File("answer.txt"),true);        //File object for writing to o/p file.
            sortedArray = performQuickSort(unsortedArray,0,unsortedArray.length-1);  //call to InsertionSort static method
            for (k = 0; k < unsortedList.size(); k++) {
                writeToAnswers.write(sortedArray[k] + "; ");                  //Writing to o/p file
            }
            writeToAnswers.write(System.lineSeparator());
            writeToAnswers.flush();
            writeToAnswers.close();
```

Comment: I'm missing the part where it says you add something in between.  What you posted there says to append no matter what.  Did I miss it?

Comment: Yeah... everytime i run the program with a file i want the results to get appended under sorting section and its performance analysis should be a new line in the table

Comment: You're going to need to draw me a picture.  Edit your question and show exactly what your program is doing now, and show then show exactly what you want it to do, carefully pointing out the difference.

Comment: See, in the output file there are 2 sections 1.Sorting results - which output the sorted sequence and 2. Performance Analysis- which is a table containing input file name, the size of array and time taken for sorting... Now,  for 2 files I need the sorting results under 1st section and other things under second heading. Right now my program will append sorting results and performance analysis at the end of the main file. But i dont want that. i want to output results under sorting section and time taken etc under performance analysis section....... Makes sense now?